# Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[X^n] > \mathbb{E}[X^{n-1}]\mathbb{E}[X]$ for all $n \geq 2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, jensen-inequality

Let $X$ denote a random variable with a smooth distribution over $[0, 1]$. Is it true that

$$\mathbb{E}[X^n] > \mathbb{E}[X^{n-1}]\mathbb{E}[X]$$

for all integers $n = 2, 3, ...$? This seems to be a simple application of Jensen's inequality: however, the exact proof eludes me!

---

*My thoughts so far:* In the case of $n = 2$, we know that

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] > \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X]^2$$

by Jensen's inequality (since the function $f(x) = x^2$ is strictly convex on $[0, 1]$).

Similarly, Jensen's inequality tells us that

$$\mathbb{E}[X^n] > \mathbb{E}[X]^{n} = \mathbb{E}[X]^{n-1}\mathbb{E}[X]$$

but that is, unfortunately, not quite the inequality I am after.

Finally, in the case where $X$ is uniformly distributed, one can calculate that

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^n] = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

and similarly

$$ \mathbb{E}[X^{n-1}] = \frac{1}{n}$$

$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}$$

which allows one to verify that

$$\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \frac{1}{n+1} > \mathbb{E}[X^{n-1}]\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2n}$$

for all $n > 1$. So this inequality holds in the uniform case, at least.

Comment: $X$ has nonnegative values?  (False with negative values allowed.)  Is that what you mean by "over $[0,1]"?

Comment: No $X$ can only take positive values, $[0, 1]$ specifically; I will edit to clarify.

Comment: @afreelunch if $X$ can take only positive values then shouldn't you write $(0, 1]$? $[0, 1]$ implies non-negative.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read @GEdgar's comment properly! Yes, $X$ takes non-negative values, specifically all the values in $[0, 1]$. (Since the distribution of $X$ is smooth, the probability that $X = 0$ is $0$, so I'm not sure how consequential the distinction is here...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_for_probability_measures), for any random variable $X$ for which $\mathbb E[|X|^n]$ exists we have

$$ \mathbb E[|X|^{n-1}]  \le (\mathbb E[|X|^n])^{(n-1)/n} $$
and
$$ \mathbb E[|X|]  \le (\mathbb E[|X|^n])^{1/n} $$
The product of these is
$$ \mathbb E[|X|^{n-1}]\; \mathbb E[|X|] \le \mathbb E[|X|^n]$$

Moreover, equality holds iff $|X|$ is almost surely equal to a constant.